# Stack different variables on on graph using stat_summary (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, statistics, summary

**Context**: I want to compare graphically the evolution of workload and trust over time during an experiment. Time is represented by 2 blocks.

**Issue**: I'm trying to plot different variables with different units on the same graph to compare the evolution. I only found that it works with geom_line, but it doesn't for stat_summary.

**Data**: x is "Block" (2 blocks) representing time. Variables used for y are "Workload" and "Trust" (both from 1 to 5, obtained by asking the subject).
To give some data:

```
data = data.frame("Subject" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), "Block" = c(1,2,1,2,1,2), "Workload" = c(1,5,2,4,3,3), "Trust" = c(4,1,3,2,2,1))
```

I tried this, it works:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Block)) + geom_line(aes(y = Trust)) + geom_line(aes(y = Workload))
```

However it does not produce a convincing result: since I have multiple points, it links them for each value so that I obtain only vertical traits. And it's perfectly normal considering what geom_line is supposed to do.
So I can still compute the mean for each block and each variable, however I was wondering if it is possible to obtain a direct result with stat_summary, using something like:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Block)) + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = line, aes(y = Trust)) + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = line, aes(y = Workload))
```

Thank you for anyone dedicating even a little of their time trying to answer that.

Have a nice day!

Pyxel

Comment: You are missing quotes around the `geom`.  Try `geom = "line"`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. However it was only when I wrote this post, I did put the quotes in R.

Comment: The code (using "line") runs fine for me.  Is the result not what you are looking for or do you get an error or ...?

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment, it works indeed. I was fooled because I was using my whole dataset, and I had a blank graph with the warning "Each group consists of only one observation". I handled it, and it works perfectly now. Thank you =)
I last thing: would you know how to add color? If I try for example "color = 'whateverColorIWant' " within the stat_summary aesthetics, it just use the normal set of colors (red, then blue, then...) and displays a legend with the color and the corresponding name "whateverColorIWant".

Comment: To set colors to constants, move `color` outside of `aes`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend summarizing your data before plotting. Consider here:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame("Subject" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), 
                 "Block" = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 "Workload" = c(1,5,2,4,3,3), 
                 "Trust" = c(4,1,3,2,2,1))
grouped <-
  df %>%
  group_by(Block) %>%
  summarise(trust = mean(Trust),
            workload = mean(Workload))

ggplot(grouped, aes(x = Block)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = trust)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = workload))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Indeed, it is a possibility.
However, as I said in the original post, this does not satisfy me completely, partly because with this I cannot plot the error bars since I only have the mean value.

Comment: You can also calculate your standard error directly when calling `summarise` above rather than using `stat.summary`